# Функциональное наследование JS (return overloaded method to parent)

Tags: javascript, функции, наследование, function-overloading

Только начал изучать данную тему. Не совсем понимаю как это работает. На следующем примере в консоли не появляется ошибок, впрочем как и ожидаемого результата. Пример был несколько сокращен.

```
function App(){
   function render(){}
   this.run = function() {
       render();
   }
}

function MainWindow(){
   App.call(this);
   function render(){
       renderFirstController();
       renderSecondController();
       renderThirdController();
   }
   this.render = render;
}

function FirstController(){
   MainWindow.call(this);
   function render(){
       console.log("Good");
       // renderFirtsBlock();
       // renderSecondBlock();
       // renderThirdBlock();
   }
   this.renderFirstController = render;
}

function ready(){
   let app = new App();
   app.run();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Ожидаемый результат - это метод App.render, но не пустой как при инициализации, а перегруженный (3 х 3 = 9) внутренними функциями. Кто-то посоветовал создавать экземпляры new Controller, но в таком случае я не понимаю где их создавать. Пример описывает модель дерева 1 х 3 х 3, но так же может и расшириться до 1 x N x N. В принципе в этом и заключается вопрос. Как вернуть родителю его перегруженный метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы чет все напутали и перемещали концепции

```
let app = new App();
```

Вы создаете экземпляр класс `App` где есть метод `run`, вызывающий `render`.  Только `render` вызывается из замыкания и больше нигде не доступен

```
App.call(this);
```

Вот эта запись ни как на `App` и его экземпляры не влияет, к тому же. Метод `run` всегда будет вызывать только один метод `render` и замыкания `App`. Используйте классы, они уже доступны и проще

```
class A {
    run() {
        this.render()
    }
    render() {}
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    render() {
        console.log('B');
    }
}

const b = new B();
b.run();
```

Comment: то есть как я понял, при функциональном наследовании (не прибегая к классам) нельзя реализовать задуманное?

Comment: мне в рамках проектной группы необходимо разобраться с функциональным наследованием и реализовать MVC (ну как вы уже поняли по названию функций Controller)

Comment: @AntonGult не совсем понимаю, что именно вам нужно, что в конце хотите получить?

Comment: @AntonGult и как хотите использовать, приведите пример

Comment: придется на пальцах объяснить. Окно MainWindow содержит пустую функцию отрисовки, от него наследуются потомки, от них тоже наследуются объекты. Каждый вложенный объект перегружает предыдущую пустую функцию родителя, и возвращает родителю  уже заполненную функцию отрисовки. Получается, что при запуске программы, она начинает отрисовывать главной функцией App.render, которая была перегруженна потомками. Сделано это для того, что у каждого отдельного потомка можно было бы менять их render, при этом не обращаясь к ним напрямую. То есть App.run - единственное видимое в клиент-приложении

Comment: @AntonGult _Каждый вложенный объект перегружает предыдущую пустую функцию родителя_ потомки не должны перезаписываться методы родителя